# AJAX. 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Совсем не давно начал заниматься фронтендом (около месяца) и скорее всего решение не трудное, но я потратил на него час времени в гугле и осмелился задать вопрос здесь, просьба не кидаться камнями если вопрос глупый.
При клике на кнопку по идее должна отправляться форма на сервер, однако получаю ошибку из заголовка

```
let message = {
    loading: 'Загрузка...',
    success: 'Спасибо! Скоро мы с вами свяжемся!',
    failure: 'Что-то пошло не так...'
};

let form = document.querySelector('.main-form'),
    input = form.getElementsByTagName('input'),
    statusMessage = document.createElement('div');

    statusMessage.classList.add('status');

    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        form.appendChild(statusMessage);
        
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', 'server.php');
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); // говорим серверу что отправим ему файлы из формы
    //работаем через атрибут name input
    let formData = new FormData(form); // Получить все данные которые ввел пользователь во все инпуты формы
    request.send(formData); //отправляем данные на сервер
    });
```

});

В панели разработчика, консоль ругается на последнюю строчку (отправка данных на сервер)

Comment: у вас сервер на чём написан? какой фреймворк? у вас там запрещено что-то делать из метода post. только другим методом........либо нужно отсылать csrf

Comment: Сервер на php, но там буквально одна строчка написана. <?php 

echo $_SERVER[‘REMOTE_ADDR‘];

Comment: И только один файл? И лежит он в той же директории?.... Возможно настройки апача запрещают по умолчанию

Comment: Большое спасибо, проблема была в том, что сервера по сути не было. На убунту я его не настраивал.